# How to get the first key object coming from an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my form I have three dynamic dropdowns. The second dropdown is based or dependent on the first drop down and the third dropdown is based and dependent on the second dropdown. So if I select on the first dropdown it will auto populate those 2 dropdowns.

Here is the code in the dropdown.

```
<!-- Service Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="service_id">Service:</label>
    <select name="service_id" class="form-control" required id="service_id">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Services</option>
            @foreach ($services as $service)
                <option value="{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->description }}</option>
            @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Categories Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="category_id">Category:</label>
    <select  name="category_id" class="form-control" required id="category_id">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Category</option>
            {{-- @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach --}}
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Categories Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="methodology_id">Method:</label>
    <select  name="methodology_id" class="form-control" required id="methodology_id">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Method</option>
            {{-- @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach --}}
    </select>
</div>
```

and here is the AJAX script below:

```
$(function() {
        $('#service_id').change(function() {

          let url = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/service/' + $(this).val() + '/categories/';

          $.get(url, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            let select = $('form select[name= category_id]');

            select.empty();

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              console.log(key + ' ' + value);
              select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
            });
          });

          let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';

          $.get(url2, function(data) {
            let select2 = $('form select[name= methodology_id]');

            select2.empty();

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              console.log(key + ' ' + value);
              select2.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
            });
          });
        });
      });
```

Now if I select the first drop down I get the correct key value object for the second dropdown.  However in the third dropdown I get the wrong object because I think I am passing the value of the first dropdown to both second and third drop down right?

In here:

```
let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';
```

Because of `$(this).val()` I am passing in the value of this function `$('#service_id').change` right?  But I think it should be the value of key in the second dropdown that will populated base on the first dropdown.  So how do I get the first key of the object in this line of code?

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
              console.log(key + ' ' + value);
              select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
            });
```

So I can pass it in the second url instead of:

```
let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';
```

It should be like:

```
let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + // incoming first key of the object from the ajax request base on the first dropdown + '/methodologies/';
```

Sorry for the bad explanation.  Appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let select = $('form select[name= category_id]');

        select.empty();

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          console.log(key + ' ' + value);
          select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
        });

          //Either grab the value from the select, or grab the first entry 
          //used in the each section above - use that in URL
          var id = select.val();
          let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + id + '/methodologies/';

          $.get(url2, function(data) {
            let select2 = $('form select[name= methodology_id]');

            select2.empty();

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              console.log(key + ' ' + value);
              select2.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
            });
          });
      });
```

I moved the second call into the first call, essentially chaining your dependencies.  Since you don't know what the list of IDS are in the first list, you have to wait for it to finish.

If you want to format it differently, [you can use promises too](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: This is the best approach for me. I would like to refactor this using promises for a cleaner look. But hey thanks a lot. Appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

Your second AJAX request needs to be made in the callback of the first, if it depends on data from the first request.